# BinaryFormatter in netstandard 1.5

Tags: c#, binaryformatter, .net-core-rc2

According to the [List of .NET CoreFx APIs and their associated .NET Platform Standard version](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md), System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters is added into to the .NET Platform Standard since 1.3, which is cool, but when I try to create a .Net Core class library targeting netstandard1.5 under.Net Core RC2, I can't use it.

The code is simple, just intending to declare a BinaryFormatter:

```
public class Problems {
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter _formatter;
}
```

Error is :

> Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Serialization' does not exist
>   in the namespace 'System.Runtime' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

Here is the project.json, which I did no modifications:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

So, is there another package that I need depend on? And Why? Shouldn't a netstandard moniker be enough for all the APIs in the list?

Comment: Hmm, no, not supporting binary serialization was [quite intentional](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/).

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, it is removed at first, however, according to [.net blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/27/making-it-easier-to-port-to-net-core/), `BinaryFormatter` is coming back to the .Net Core, but apparently not in RC2.

Comment: .net blog just published [the roadmap of .Net Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/), and according to it, binary serialization will not be available until 2017.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters` package was added after RC2, it should be included in the 1.0 release tomorrow. In the meantime, you can use a version from [MyGet](https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/dotnet-core).
- The 1.0 version of `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters` will not contain `BinaryFormatter`. It mostly contains serialization attributes and interfaces, and types used by them. [The full API of that package is here.](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/1.0.0/src/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters/ref/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.cs)
- Even then, `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters` is not referenced by `NETStandard.Library`. If you want to use it, you will need to explicitly add it to your project.json.
- [`BinaryFormatter` will be available in a future version of .Net Core.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/27/making-it-easier-to-port-to-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks! And yes, `BinaryFormatter` is not in `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters`, it is actually in `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary` . I might got confused with the two namespaces.

Comment: And why `NETStandard.Library` doesn't reference `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters`? What is it on earth?

Comment: @JarenDuan `NETStandard.Library` references just the most common common .Net Core packages, it does not reference all of them.

Comment: Yes. and we can find more information about `NETStandard.Library` [on this page](https://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/packages.html).  The dotnet core docs website is becoming more and more useful. And thanks to @svick, again.

Comment: Attention! The .net core docs pages seemed to be moved from github.io to learn.microsoft.com after .Net Core 1.0 is released, for example, the one about packages is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/packages) now

Comment: @svick, I have a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355667/is-it-possible-to-deserialize-binary-data-into-an-object-in-net-core-when-the)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot find `BinaryFormatter` in RC2,

http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/

About whether it would be part of .NET Core, you can refer to this pull request,

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/8302/files

I guess it would be part of .NET Core 1.0 RTM, or 1.1 release.

Comment: Thanks, and the website you mentioned is very useful to explore .net packages. Wish RTM can get it work.