# How do I deserialize binary data into an object in .net Core, when the initial object was serialized with Full .net Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, .net-core

I have an application which stores some data in a SQL database in a binary field. These data are serialized from a .net object in traditional .NET application with [binary serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm writing a .net core application that needs to interface with the above but reading the binary data and making sense of them.

Ideally I want to be able just to deserialize these data with .net Core as if I was running full .net framework. The data itself are not complex, they are just a `Dictionary<string,string>` produced by the old [asp.net profile provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478953.aspx).

I need to both read and write the binary data from .net core code.

I understand that support for BinaryFormatter [is coming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38039023/284111) to .net core. In the meanwhile, is there anything not very complicated I can do *right now* to serialize / deserialize data with .net core as full .net framework would?

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: @LeiYang, what are you suggesting to try?

Comment: maybe i misunderstood you. i'm not familiar with .net core.  do you mean in .net core you did not find a formatter?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we have to write our own BinaryReader/BinaryWriter methods...

**SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.BinaryTest (
    BinaryData varbinary(max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;

namespace StackOverflow.ConsoleTester
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const String SqlConnectionString = @"Server={Server};Database={Database};User={User};Password={Password};";

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
            {
                var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.BinaryTest;", db) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };

                db.Open();

                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            using (var db = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
            {
                var serializedData = new Dictionary<String, String> {{"key1", "value1"}, {"key2", "value2"}};

                var binaryData = WriteBinaryData(serializedData);

                var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.BinaryTest (BinaryData) VALUES (@BinaryData);", db) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };

                var parameter = new SqlParameter("BinaryData", SqlDbType.VarBinary) {Value = binaryData};

                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                db.Open();

                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            Dictionary<String, String> deserializedData = null;

            using (var db = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
            {
                var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT BinaryData FROM dbo.BinaryTest", db) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };

                db.Open();

                var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    deserializedData = ReadBinaryData(reader.GetSqlBinary(0));
                }
            }

            if (deserializedData != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in deserializedData)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {item.Key}; Value: {item.Value}");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static Byte[] WriteBinaryData(Dictionary<String, String> data)
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                binaryWriter.Write(item.Key);
                binaryWriter.Write(item.Value);
            }

            var binaryData = memoryStream.ToArray();

            return binaryData;
        }

        private static Dictionary<String, String> ReadBinaryData(SqlBinary data)
        {
            var model = new Dictionary<String, String>();

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data.Value);
            var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);

            while (binaryReader.BaseStream.Position != binaryReader.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                model.Add(binaryReader.ReadString(), binaryReader.ReadString());
            }

            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of libraries that do serialization / de-serialization. For example [protobuf](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) or [BinaryFormatter](https://github.com/lukasz-pyrzyk/BinaryFormatter). They do not help whatsoever in reading (or writing) whatever standard .Net Binary Serializer produces. Unless I'm missing something, your code does not help with this either. You might want to try to Serialize something with the standard .NET facilities, and then see if your code can deserialize the result. It does not look like it can.